# How to remove captions and labels for sub figures ? How to decrease auto vertical spacing between sub figures?

Tags: captions, subfloats, minipage, subcaption, subfig

I am beginner in LaTeX, and I am writing my Ms c thesis. I use TeXstudio for this. I have the following code with a customized `mfthesis` document class. I have sub figures defined using `minipage` environment in the code. There are 3 sub figures on top of each other. I want to remove sub figures' captions and labels (I want nothing on the sub figures), but have a single main caption and label. Also, I want to decrease the auto vertical space between these sub figures, because I think it is too much. Could Any body please help in this regard??
Thank you.

```
\documentclass[English,MSC,Times,NoIndent,IEEE]{mfthesis}

\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % image uses Times
\usepackage{cite}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newcommand{\der}[2]{\frac{d#1}{d#2}}

\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.85\textwidth} 
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Fig_4_4a}
        \caption{}
        \label{}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.85\textwidth} 
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Fig_4_4b}
        \caption{}
        \label{}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.85\textwidth} 
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Fig_4_4c}
        \caption{}
        \label{}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{(a) bla bla bla (b) bla bla bla (c) bla bla bla}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\caption*{}`!

Comment: BTW, is there an incompatibility between mfthesis and the subcaption package?

Comment: No, there is no incompatibility. What I wanted was simple as @zarko replied below. \captions* didn't work for this case. But now it is solved, thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove mini pages, captions and labels in it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth]{example-image-duck}%{Fig_4_4a}

    \medskip
    \includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth]{example-image-duck}%{Fig_4_4b}

    \medskip
    \includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth]{example-image-duck}%{Fig_4_4c}
    \caption{(a) bla bla bla (b) bla bla bla (c) bla bla bla}
    \label{fig:threeimage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you like to have more vertical space between image, insert for example `\bigskip` (or  `\space{<desired vertical space>}`) before second and third `\includegraphics`.

Comment: Perfect! I am very grateful for you, Thank you very much.

Comment: ```smallskip``` and ```medskip``` didn't show obvious vertical space! Is there any other command or way to do that?

Comment: What is "obvious vertical space" for you? You ask for reduced space in question ... If `\medskip` is not sufficient, try whit `\space{<desired vertical space>}`. See edited answer.

Comment: I'm partial to `\vspace{\floatsep}` between rows of subfigures.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, good idea. In the first I reduce space (to `\smallskip`) between images by purpose, accordingly to OP demand that space between images had to be reduced. Well now seems that vertical space is to small. Since this is opinion based demand I will left experimenting and deciding, which vertical space is appropriate, to OP.

Comment: @Zarko ```\space{<desired vertical space>}``` worked perfectly. Thank you very much.